# additional rpms to offline centos iso

Tags: centos7

I try to create custom iso of CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) with additional rpms installation.
I downloaded all rpms, put them in Packages directory, recreate repodata with following command:

```
createrepo -dpo .. . -g mkiso/repodata/blabla-c7-minimal-x86_64-comps.xml
```

Everything looks fine, but after the OS installation start I get the error:

> You have specified that the package 'rpm-name' should be installed. This package does not exist. Would you like to continue the install without this package ?

There is my ks.cfg file:

```
#version=DEVEL
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use installation media
cdrom
# Firewall configuration
firewall --enabled
# Use graphical install
graphical
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8
# SELinux configuration
selinux --disabled
# reboot after installing
reboot
# Network information

network --device=eth3 --onboot=no --noipv4 --noipv6
network --device=usb0 --onboot=no --noipv4 --noipv6

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted *****
# System services
services --enabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone Europe/Moscow --isUtc
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sdg
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all
# Disk partitioning information
part /boot/efi --fstype="efi" --ondisk=sdg --size=200 --fsoptions="umask=0077,shortname=winnt"
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sdg --size=500
part pv.01 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=sdg --size=81219
volgroup centos --pesize=4096 pv.01
logvol / --fstype="xfs" --size=77120 --name=root --vgname=centos
logvol swap --fstype="swap" --size=4096 --name=swap --vgname=centos
%packages
@^minimal
@core
chrony
kexec-tools

MariaDB-10.1.21-centos7-x86_64-client.rpm
MariaDB-10.1.21-centos7-x86_64-common.rpm
MariaDB-10.1.21-centos7-x86_64-devel.rpm
MariaDB-10.1.21-centos7-x86_64-shared.rpm


%end
%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'
%end
%post --log=/root/ks.log

%end
```

Comment: Those are the _file_ names, but not the _package_ names.

Comment: i tried MariaDB-shared and so on, but have same result